# Getting environment variable LOGONSERVER in an ASP/MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, environment-variables, httpcontext

I know how to get the LOGONSERVER environment variable via this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOGONSERVER");
```

However, if my application is an ASP/MVC3 application, this is going to give me the logon server for the box that IIS is running on right? Not the logonserver for the browser who's request I am processing. I know I can use this to get the users logon name server-side

```
HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.User.Identity.Name
```

But I don't see anything in that namespace that will give me logonserver either.

I now I can grab it client-side via javascript but I have to execute a CreateObject which will force the "ActiveX" authorization request in the browser.

Any other ideas?

Comment: The only way you're going to get that information is from an ActiveX plugin, and of course it may or may not be available at all depending on your user population.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a way around this, and eventually put this shared function into the Global.asax.

```
    Public Shared Function GetDC() As String
        'Determine DNS domain name from RootDSE object
        Dim objRootDSE As Object = GetObject("LDAP://<myDomain>/RootDSE")
        Dim strNamingContext As String = objRootDSE.Get("rootDomainNamingContext")
        Dim lcDC As Object = objRootDSE.Get("dnsHostName")

        Return lcDC.ToString()
    End Function
```

You can then use it
`<%= MyGlobalAsaxClassName.GetDC() %>`

Comment: This doesn't exactly get the server authenticating your users, but does return you a DC to query against.